# File containg all google font URLs

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api, postcss

I'm building a set of utilities for applying google fonts - [superfly-css-utilities-fonts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superfly-css-utilities-fonts).

I would like to include all the Google font urls such that the utility classes can be built like this:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

    /** All fonts fallback to the same variable - FIX **/
    @each $font in Open+Sans, Montserrat, Roboto, Lato {
        .u-font-$(font) {
          font-family: $(font) !important;
        }
    }
```

Anyone know if theres a file containing all the `@import` statements for all the google fonts?  That way I could just import that file.  If there existed a comma separated list of all the font names that could be used in the each loop that would be awesome.

This work is going into an MIT licensed utility library.

Comment: ALL of the fonts? Woah that's a lot of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Import all Google Fonts

[Easy Fonts](https://pagecdn.com/lib/easyfonts) allows you to load selective fonts, or all fonts at once. It also includes CSS classes for all fonts so that you do not have to edit CSS to make fonts to work.

```
<link href="https://pagecdn.io/lib/easyfonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Dude - THAT IS AWESOME!!!  Thanks!!!  I'll be pasting it at the top of this file: https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-utilities-fonts/blob/master/src/main/css/index.css

Comment: The [superfly-css-task-build](https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-task-build) uses uncss to remove all unused test CSS.  I'm also going to make a task that removes all unused CSS prior to deployment.