# Converting a postcss loop variable value to lowercase

Tags: css, postcss

I have a postcss loop that looks like this:

```
    @each $font in Montserrat, Roboto, Lato {
        .u-font-$(font) {
          font-family: $(font) !important;
        }
    }
```

I would like the utility names to be all lowercase.  So I would need something like this `.u-font-lowercasefn($(font))`.  Any idea if something like this exists?

Comment: why not typing them initially lowercase?

Comment: I'm looking to turn all the google fonts into css utilities as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660747/file-containg-all-google-font-urls    So I'm looking at various options for doing the processing.